# In Facebook login, how do you see the permissions that the user granted?

Tags: javascript, facebook

As of December 2011, Facebook [changed their API](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/) and broke everyone's [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/). The following code will no longer work:

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
      console.info('you logged in');
      if (response.perms) {
        console.info('you granted some permissions');
      }
    }
  }, {
    perms: 'publish_stream'
  }
);
```

Instead you have to do this:

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.info('you are logged in', response);
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'publish_stream'
  }
);
```

This at least makes login work, but I'm no longer able to see if they accepted my requested permission or not. When I log out the response, it does not contain a "perms" key anymore:

```
response: {
  authResponse {    
    accessToken: string,
    expiresIn: number,
    signedRequest: string,
    userID: string
  },
  status
}
```

Comment: Is it even possible to connect to the application without accepting all requested permissions?

Comment: @zerkms : Did they change this behavior too? Before December 2011, you were allowed to log in even though you denied permissions. In this situation, I could still read the user's name and user ID but wasn't allowed to publish to their wall.

Comment: hm... haven't seen this ever. IIRC when you press "don't allow" - you just follow the callback url without active session, don't you?

Comment: 2 years ago, I remember testing the path of logging in but denying permissions. Facebook changes their API too often and is never backwards compatible. You can post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know user cannot connect to the application without confirming **all** the requested permissions.

I admit I may be wrong but as a user and developer I haven't seen it is possible.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: me too ;-) but most likely it is just one of the newbies I was too "rude" with ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it will say connected regardless. you might have to query for the perms.